# Placing a block with an absolute space to the left and floating characteristic from the top

Tags: html, css

I want to display bars using HTML and css:

```
 <style type="text/css">
      #container {
        position: relative;
        height:20px;
      }
      .bar {
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        height:100%;
        background-color:orange;
        border:1px solid black;
      }
    </style>

<div id="container">
  <div class="bar" style="left:0px; width:100px">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar" style="left:20px; width:30px">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar" style="left:110px; width:10px">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysbrk/)

It is important that each bar has the correct width and exact distance to the left as stated in the inline-CSS. The bars are generated dynamically and I have no influence on their order and no possibility to determine if one bar overlaps the other.

The normal HTML-output produces an overlap between bars #1 and #2. However, I'd love to have no overlap between the bars and see bar #2 under bar #1 but with correct distance to the left.

I cannot manually change the `top` setting for each bar that would be overlapped, so I'm looking for a dynamic solution. TIA

Comment: Put in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EYvVM/

Comment: What have you tried? Where on earth is the problem? Just change the coordinats and that's it. -1 until you fix

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Why would the bars "change positions" if you have them set to `position: absolute`? Perhaps you're looking for [`float: left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) instead of `position: absolute;`.

Comment: Yes it wont work with absolute positions, unless you have another meaning for the absolute? http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/yNRU6/

Comment: I added the restrictions to the questions. After reading the first post again I would've probably downvoted myself. Sorry. I cannot use `float: left` because the space between the (absolute) left of the container must be exactly the value of the `left` attribute.

Comment: @Travesty3: I ned a mixture of an absolute placement from the left (that's why I'm going for absolute) and a floating placement from the top. This is where I'm stuck..

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for a combination of `position: absolute` and `float: left`. Try putting the bars in another container which has a set width and is absolutely positioned where you want the bars to be, and then float each of the bars left within the container. Like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysbrk/1/) (try changing the size of your window to see what happens)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="abs">
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:green; width:30px">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="bar" style="background-color:blue; width:100px">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="bar" style="width:10px">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    height:20px;
}
#abs {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    width: 50%;
}
.bar {
    height:100%;
    background-color:orange;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
```

---

I don't think you can do what you want without using JavaScript. You've indicated that a JS solution wouldn't work for you, but perhaps this solution will be useful to anyone else stumbling across this post. This will likely need tweaking, but it should give a basic idea as to how this could be done:

[jQuery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Ysbrk/3/)

```
var lastX = 0;
$('.bar').each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).css('left')) < lastX) {
        $(this).css('top', parseInt($(this).css('top'))+25);
    } else {
        lastX = lastX + $(this).width();
    }
});
```

Comment: The containers should not be floated to the left at all, because the space to the left must be fixed as stated in the inline css..

Comment: I don't think what you want to do can be done with just HTML and CSS. You could probably accomplish this with JavaScript. Is jQuery an option?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.. :(

Comment: I agree that the chances are looking pretty slim that this can be done without JS.

Comment: @thoughtgap: Sorry, it looks like I can't really help you without JS. I added a sample jQuery solution to anyone else that might find it useful.

Comment: @Travesty3: I'm glad you posted a jQuery solution anyway, since this problem was bugging me. Your jsFiddle only accommodates two rows of bars, though. I modified it (http://jsfiddle.net/Ysbrk/5/) to generalize for more bars. It could still use some more tweaking, though, since it won't always fill all the available gaps, depending on the order they appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the bars to flow more naturally, not overlapping, maybe absolutely positioning them isn't the right path. Try `float: left`, which will put them on the same line if there's room; otherwise, it will move below.

And when you say bar #2 doesn't show at all if you change the order of the tags, that's because of the z-order. It's displaying behind the larger bar, so it's not visible at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only with absolute position then u will have to position them like this.

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="bar" style="left:0px; width:100px">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar" style="left:110px; width:30px">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="bar" style="left:140px; width:10px">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

If you can use other ways u can do it with `float:left;` with margin.

Hope this helps